# How to join based on partial match

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, numpy

I have a dataset that looks like this:

```
data1 = {'title': ['A Quiet Place','Harry Potter 1', 'Short Stories'], 'Author': ['AAA, BBB, CCC, DDD', 'XXX, MMM, EEE, FFF', 'GGG, HHH, IIII, JJJ']}  
df = pd.DataFrame(data1)
```

I have another dataset that looks like this:

```
data2 = {'authordf2': ['AAA', 'EEE'], 'Sales': [10,20]}
df2 = pd.DataFrame(data2)
```

I want to merge these datasets based on partial string match between df and df2, so I get this:

```
data3 = {'title': ['A Quiet Place','Harry Potter 1', 'Short Stories'], 'Author': ['AAA, BBB, CCC, DDD', 'XXX, MMM, EEE, FFF', 'GGG, HHH, IIII, JJJ'],'Authordf2': ['AAA', 'EEE',None],'Sales': [10, 20,None]}  
df3 = pd.DataFrame(data3)
```

Could someone please help?

Comment: I don't know what you mean by "based on partial string match".

Comment: By partial string match I meant that the 'authordf2' string can be found anywhere within the 'author' string in df. I've updated my post above to clarify my example

Answer (score 1):

I hope this is what you are looking, the logic I captured is `'A, B, C, D'` should start with column values from df2. It is not a partial match to what you are asking, but based on your desired result. If you go for partial match use `in` operator like `min(x, key=len) in max(x, key=len)`. Then `A, B, C, D` should match with `A` as well as `C`, but according to your desired output it is only matching with `A`

You can edit the `df_final` and rename the columns as you want.

```py
df_merged = pd.merge(df, df2, how='cross') # cartesian join

df_final = pd.merge(df, 
         df_merged[df_merged[['Author', 'authordf2']].apply(lambda x: min(x, key=len) in max(x, key=len)), axis=1)],
         on='title',
         how='left')

df_final
```

|  | title | Author_x | Author_y | authordf2 | Sales |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | A Quiet Place | A, B, C, D | A, B, C, D | A | 10 |
| 1 | Harry Potter 1 | C, D, E, F | C, D, E, F | C | 20 |
| 2 | Short Stories | G, H, I, J | nan | nan | nan |

Comment: Apologies, by partial match I meant that 'authordf2' can be found anywhere within the 'author' string in df. I've updated my post above to clarify my example.

Comment: I hope the above solution will work, please check and let me know.